# Finding a random element in an 2D array,then performing operations on it

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, random

I need to find a random element in a 2D array, as the title says.  Then I need to perform an operation on this.

For example:

```
Grid = np.zeros((64,64))
ones = np.ones((32,64))
minus = -1 * ones
Grid[0:32,:] = ones[:]
Grid[32:64,:] = minus[:]
```

So its half full of 1's, half of -1's.  Then I need to select a random element of this 2D array,and perform an operation on it.

For example it needs to do something like:

```
def change(Grid):
    Grid[0,0] *= -1
```

But for a random element inside this list, but obviously the below code doesn't work.

```
Grid[random.choice,random.choice] *= -1
```

Is there a way to do this with `random.choice`, or is there another way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already in NumPy, you could use `np.random.randint`:

```
n, m = Grid.shape
row = np.random.randint(0, n)
col = np.random.randint(0, m)
Grid[row, col] *= -1
```